# Are there any rules for variable naming convention in visual studio, which can be enforced while development?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, lint, rules

I was looking for a naming convention rule in static code analyser library of Visual studio dotnet but didn't find.

ie.
**Name should be in camelCase.**

```
var AgerageAge=10;// rule error: Name should be in camelCase
var averageAge=10; //Correct
```

Though, all other rules are there in the library but not able to find this particular rule which I want to enforce in my project for consistency.

Here is a list of Code analyser in my project.

[image]

Is there anything else I would have to do list that rule here and enforce?

Comment: Yes re-sharper and style cop, however style cop is more hassle than its worth, and you will eventually regret the day you installed it

Comment: R# rocks... As @MichaelRandall said StyleCop may drive enough people insane :)  If you are looking for something free search term is "c# lint" - https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html is referred to in one of off-topic recommendation questions (no personal experience).

Comment: @Michael, Re-sharper makes visual studio slower and I tried to use style cop, which requires building the project to run those rules (even sometimes it doesn't work :-)) and my requirement is to enforce rules while development.

Comment: @Alexei, I tried sonarlint as well again the same problem, I don't know why Microsoft doesn't provide these basic rule?

Answer (score 4):

You can set this directly within the Visual Studio IDE.

These settings can be exported to a `.editorconfig` file, which you'd commit into your source control repository so that it will apply to all developers.

For example, if you go to **Tools** -> **Options**, then expand down to **Text Editor**, then **C#**, then **Code Style** and finally **Naming**, you'll see something like this:

[image: Code Formatting Options]

As you'll see, you can change the **Severity** so that it generates an error.

[image: Severity]

Looking back up at the **Code Style** tree level, you see an option to create an `.editorconfig` file from these settings:

[image: Export .editor config]

A good reference for the Editor Config rules: [.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference.md).

Getting more specific, good documentation is available here **for VS 2017**: [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Thanks, @Bredan Green, I'm not seeing any option 'generate .editorconfig file from settings'?

Comment: What version of VS are you running?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017

Comment: @Bredan, I don't find any rules for variables in this? actually, I want to apply this rule inside a function when variable naming rules have been violated?